# Desired number of result rows as parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I'd like to allow my consumer to specify the number of rows they want returned in a stored procedure.  I'm looking to mimic this behavior:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 AccountId ,
        AccountName
FROM    dbo.Account
```

But in this fashion:

```
DECLARE @resultCount INT = 100;

SELECT  TOP @resultCount AccountId ,
        AccountName
FROM    dbo.Account
```

Of course the 2nd version results in an "Incorrect syntax near @resultCount" error.  Is there a way to do this without breaking down to contatenating SQL strings and using EXEC?  I find that is not very maintainable.

Comment: Just put parenthesis around `@resultCount`: `SELECT  TOP (@resultCount) AccountId ...`

Comment: I believe the method you want to avoid is the only one that will work.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add parenthesis `(` `)` around `@resultCount` :

```
DECLARE @resultCount INT = 100;

SELECT  TOP (@resultCount) AccountId ,
        AccountName
FROM    dbo.Account
```

Comment: OK, I'm embarrassed I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

B. Using TOP with a variable
The following example uses a variable to specify the number of employees that are returned in the query result set.
Transact-SQL

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @p AS int = 10;
SELECT TOP (@p) JobTitle, HireDate, VacationHours
FROM HumanResources.Employee
ORDER BY VacationHours DESC
GO
```

So in your case...

```
SELECT  TOP (@resultCount) AccountId ,
        AccountName
FROM    dbo.Account
```